# Are Indian police allowed by law to slap citizens?

Tags: police, india, punishment

I have seen a few [instances](https://redd.it/erq2lx) where the Indian police slap citizens as a fast punishment. Is that explicitly allowed by law, or just tolerated in practice?

[image]

Comment: It looks like these people have illegally boarded the ladies' coach of Metro train, which is a punishable offense. In such cases, police can punish(slap)/warn/fine them. Since these are like more than 50 people it is tough. Slap one or two can really set a good example for the rest of the others. However, filming it and then make it viral gives a person the right to smack legal defamation on police or media or a person who is defaming.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The legal hook is [reported](https://www.policinglaw.info/country/india) to be [§129 of the Code of Criminal Procedure](https://indiankanoon.org/doc/1216752/), which authorizes use of force to disperse an illegal assembly, which this sort of is. No statute that I can find states that police can smack lawbreakers who are forced to disperse, but as is common in common law countries, the laws of India are not fully explicit on that which is allowed or forbidden for police to do. As [this article](https://www.files.ethz.ch/isn/151470/IAVA-IB3-A-Heavy-Hand.pdf) indicates, systematic limits on police use of force remain to be developed.